# How to get the date time value from input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I'm using [datetimepicker library](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) from github for my angular project. It's working fine when I select the date and time. But when I add `ng-model` to the input field, and retrieve it, the input field shows empty. It doesn't update the field based on the ng-model.

**Directive**

```
App.directive('jsDatetimepicker', function () {
 return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var options = (typeof scope.$eval(attrs.jsDatetimepicker) !== 'undefined') ? scope.$eval(attrs.jsDatetimepicker) : new Object();

        jQuery(element).datetimepicker({
            format: options.format ? options.format : false,
            useCurrent: options.useCurrent ? options.useCurrent : false,
            locale: moment.locale('' + (options.locale ? options.locale : '') +''),
            showTodayButton: options.showTodayButton ? options.showTodayButton : false,
            showClear: options.showClear ? options.showClear : false,
            showClose: options.showClose ? options.showClose : false,
            sideBySide: options.sideBySide ? options.sideBySide : false,
            inline: options.inline ? options.inline : false,
            icons: {
                time: 'si si-clock',
                date: 'si si-calendar',
                up: 'si si-arrow-up',
                down: 'si si-arrow-down',
                previous: 'si si-arrow-left',
                next: 'si si-arrow-right',
                today: 'si si-size-actual',
                clear: 'si si-trash',
                close: 'si si-close'
            }
        });
    }
 };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="example-datetimepicker5" data-js-datetimepicker="" type="text" name="example-datetimepicker5" placeholder="Choose a date.." ng-model="news.new_date" class="form-control"/>
<label for="example-datetimepicker5">Date</label>
<button ng-click="CreateNews()" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Create</button>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.news = {};
$scope.news.new_date = "";
$scope.CreateNews = function(){
 alert(JSON.stringify($scope.news.new_date));
}
```

**Output**

```
new_date returns empty
```

**Expected**

```
new_date returns datetime
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can very well use this

```
$("#example-datetimepicker5").on("dp.change", function() {

    $scope.selecteddate = $("#example-datetimepicker5").val();
    alert("selected date is " + $scope.selecteddate);

});
```

Comment: I'm using angularJS, jQuery '$' should ignore.

Comment: You can use JQuery in angularjs, but you need to add Lib for it